# flutter library dart:html using eval from javascript

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, dart-html

I need js method `eval()` in Flutter Dart code. How I can get it? I try import

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js';
```

But I still do not have `eval()` method. Any idea how to import this method?
I need evaluate expression like in this js sample: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_eval but in Dart code, so I try import this eval() function from dart:js but my compiler still not see `eval()` method.

HTML code (working):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<script>
  var a = "person.name=='James'";
  var person = {'name':'James'};
  var result = eval(a);
  console.log(result);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Dart code (not working - do not see definition of eval though import html and js lib):

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js';
  
void main() {
  var a = "person.name=='James'";
  var person = {'name':'James'};
  var result = eval(a);
  print(result);
}
```

Any idea how to import javascript method `eval()` into dart code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```dart
final result = js.context.callMethod("eval",a);
print(result);
```

And there is whole code:

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;
  
void main() {
  var a = "person.name=='James'";
  var person = {'name':'James'};
  final result = js.context.callMethod("eval",[person,a]);
  print(result);
}
```

Comment: thank You! with some changes, Your solution working ;)